# What is the difference between git describe --abbrev=0 and git describe --abrev=0 --tags

Tags: git

I have a repo with the following output:

> ```
> $ git tag
> product-picker-v1
> v0.0.1
> v0.0.2
> v0.0.3
> v0.0.4
> v0.1
> v0.1.1
> v0.1.10
> v0.1.11
> v0.1.12
> v0.1.12.1
> v0.1.13
> v0.1.14
> v0.1.15
> v0.1.2
> v0.1.3
> v0.1.4
> v0.1.5
> v0.1.6
> v0.1.7
> v0.1.8
> v0.1.9
> ```

```
$ git describe --abbrev=0
v0.1.14

$ git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
v0.1.15
```

Why do I get one tag back when I run git describe without the `--tags` option?

Answer (score 6):

It is right in the documents: `--tags` draws from all tags, not just annotated ones.

[git-describe Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)